# Jquery object array?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I dont know how can explain, following code works

```
function DrawIrregularChartGrid() {
    $('#data_grid').datagrid({
        columns: [[{"field":"MeterID","title":"MeterID"},{"field":"ADateTime","title":"ADateTime"}]]
    });
}
```

but this one does not work, there is no error message, grid is loading but col names are null.

```
function DrawIrregularChartGrid() {
    $('#data_grid').datagrid({
        columns: [GetGridColumnNames()]
    });
}
```

`GetGridColumnNames()`

returns

`[{"field":"MeterID","title":"MeterID"},{"field":"ADateTime","title":"ADateTime"}]`

**GetGridColumnNames function**

```
function GetGridColumnNames() {

var cols = [];
var IrregularChartParams = InitializeChartParams();

// parametreleri json stringe cevir...
var chartParams = JSON.stringify(IrregularChartParams);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: app_base_url + 'Graph/GetGridColumnNames',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: chartParams,
    success: function (result) {
        $.each(result, function (index, value) {
            cols.push(result);
        });
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    },
    beforeSend: function () {

    },
    complete: function () {
    }
});
return cols;
}
```

dataGrid column property type is object array. How can assign `GetGridColumnNames` returning object to `columns` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because your AJAX call is *asynchronous*, so `cols` is empty when the function returns.

You need to *defer* all subsequent operations until the `success:` call has finished.  Better yet, remove the `success:` and `error:` handlers and use explicit deferred objects, i.e.:

```
function GetGridColumnNames() {
    return $.ajax(...).then(
        function(result) {
            // pre-process result and _return_ the desired array
            ...
            return cols;
        },
        function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            // error handling
        },
    }
}

GetGridColumnNames().done(function(cols) {
    // use column names here
});
```

The `.then` call is being passed two callbacks - one to pre-process the returned JSON data, and the other to handle errors.

Comment: +1, beat me to it, but this has to be a duplicate of a billion questions just like it ?

Comment: the question might be a dup, the answer isn't ;-)